# Have div appear to the right of a TD onclick of TD with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a absolute positioned div of 5x5 pixel square.

If I have a table say

```
<table><tr><td>Something</td></tr></table>
```

I want the div to show up exactly to the right of the TD when I click anywhere inside of the TD, so it should appear snapped to the right side of the TD regardless of where I click in the TD. Is there a simple way to accomplish this in Jquery/Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using hidden `table` cells, and showing the `div` within that:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td class="hidden"><div></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td class="hidden"><div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('tr td').click(
    function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.hidden').toggle();
    });
```

CSS:

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.hidden div {
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MyVwH/).

---

**Edited** to revise the content a little, so that the containing (`.hidden`) `td` is always visible (to reduce the chance of page jumping around due to suddenly appearing table cells):

jQuery:

```
$('tr td').click(

function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.hidden div').toggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
table {
    empty-cells: show;
}

td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
}

td:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.2);
}

.hidden div {
    display: none;
}

.hidden div {
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MyVwH/1/).

---

**Edited** as per @Nicky Waite's suggestion (below):

> Maybe stick your hover on the tr element.

```
$('tr').click(

function() {
    $(this).find('.hidden div').toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MyVwH/2/).

Comment: If he can change the markup then this is a nice easy solution.

Comment: @Nicky, thanks; if he can't change the mark-up then it could be trickier.  :)

Comment: Maybe stick your hover on the tr element

Comment: @Nicky, I thought about that but I remember discounting it, for some reason. I can't remember *why*, though. And it seems to be a good idea...(I'll edit the answer to include it as an option. Thanks!)

Comment: Ah...that might be why I discounted it, he explicitly says 'click' in his question... =) On the other hand, if he'd prefer to use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) I'd be happy to provide another edit... XD

Comment: Doh I mean with your css there :)

Comment: @Nicky: ahahahaha... ohhh, it's been a *long* day... XD

Answer (score 0):

give the TD relative position. and put the div inside it. give your div

`right:0px;`

on click

give your div style of:

```
left:50%;
margin-left:-2px //(these might need to be change a bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the `<td>` that you want to put a `<td>` after using a jQuery selector (either using a class or id), and use $.append()

Here are your options for selecting a jQuery tag

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

So something like

```
$("td").click(function(event) {
     $(this).append("<td></td>");
});
```

Comment: And yeah, style it like the other guy said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could handle it in a few ways. Here's one thought:

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
  el = $(e.target);
  el.after("<div class='my_square' />");
  sq = $(el + " + .my_square");
  sq.css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: el.offset().left,
    top: el.offset().top + el.outerHeight() / 2
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using positions.  Although I wasn't sure if you wanted multiple boxes or just one.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/DvTBR/

```
$(function() {

$('#summary td').click(function() {

    var td = $(this);
    var position = td.position();
    $('#link').css({
        top: position.top + (td.height() / 2),
        left: position.left + td.width() + 10
    }).show();

});

});

<div id="link"></div>
<table id="summary">
<tr><td>Toast</td></tr>
<tr><td>Toast</td></tr>
</table>

#link {
width:5px;
height:5px;
background-color:royalblue;
display:none;  
position:absolute;
}
```